# use C# Excel DNA with C# Window Form

Tags: excel, excel-dna

ContextSwitchDeadlock occurred Message: Managed Debugging Assistant 'ContextSwitchDeadlock' has detected a problem in 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE'. Additional information: The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0xfd30d6e0 to COM context 0xfd30d5b8 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages. This situation generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, all single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long running operations.

Working on Excel DNA have a function to refresh sheet also refresh and update sheet but I'm getting exception as I'm share

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First open Exception dialog using ctrl+alt+E command then go Managed Debugging Assistants and uncheck ContextSwitchDeadlock[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUR2P.png)